# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_array() on boolean

Tags: php

I am trying to load data from database, but it shows the error 
"Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_array() on boolean "
please help me to solve this error..

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <?php include 'db.php'; ?>
   <html>
   <head>
    <title>Chat System in PHP</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" media="all"/>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div id="Container">
    <div id="Chat_box">
        <?php 

            $query = "SELECT * FROM chat_system ORDER BY id DESC";
            $run = $db->query($query);

        while($row = $run-> fetch_array()):
        ?>
        <div id="Chat_data">
            <span style="color:blue;"> <?php echo $row ['name']; ?> </span>:
            <span style="color:brown;"><?php echo $row ['msg']; ?></span>
            <span style="float:right; color:silver;"><?php $row['date'];?>
        </span>
        </div>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        </div>

        <form action="index.php" method="POST">

        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter Name">
        <textarea name="msg" placeholder="Enter Message"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send">

        </form>
        </div>

        </body>
        </html>
```

and here is the db.php file for database connection..

```
<?php

$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = "";
$db_name = "chat_system";

$db = new mysqli($host,$user,$pass,$db_name);


?>
```

Comment: Take a look on how to use `mysqli` : http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.statements.php

Comment: Change `while($row = $run-> fetch_array()):` to `while($row = $run->fetch_array()):` NOTE: Close space after `$run-> fetch_array()`

Comment: @LasVegasCoder closing the space will do nothing

Comment: @WillParky93 didn't say will cause the error, but a note for good coding practice.

Answer (score 0):

In [php docs](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) you can read

> Returns FALSE on failure. For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or EXPLAIN queries mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result object. For other successful queries mysqli_query() will return TRUE

Probably you have an error in the query or in db connection... can you share table structure and verify the db connection params?

Comment: thank you for your help. there was a problem in table name.

Comment: glad to be helpful :)

Comment: Please do not use answers to ask clarification questions. That should be done in comments.